# How do you use the buffer? [intel based assembly]

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, char

I am having trouble figuring out how to use the buffer in my code. The code is supposed to loop through and count the number of each char is in the array. I haven't written the function for lower case and upper case chars yet but for the int part it outputs "0 - +0" every time no matter what combination of integers or letters I input. I'm not sure if this issue has to do with the buffer or if its from another part of my code. Any suggestions, tips, or explanations are welcome. I am compiling on Visual Studios 2015 with the kip irvine library.

```
.data
    buffer BYTE 1064 DUP(?)
    ;sentence input
    sentence dword ? 
    ;enter gallons prompt
    prompt1 BYTE "Enter the sentence you would like to count: ", 0
    ;start of int values
    intEnd dword 57
    ;int you are on
    intIndex dword 48
    ;upper char you are on
    upcharIndex dword 65
    ;start of upper case char values
    upcharEnd dword 90
    ;lower char you are on
    lowCharIndex dword 97
    ;start of lower case char values
    lowcharEnd dword 122
    ;prompt dash
    dash BYTE " - "
    ;count vals
    count dword 0
.code
main PROC
    ;shows the prompt
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString    
    mov edx, OFFSET buffer
    mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
    ;reads the sentence the user inputs
    call ReadString
    mov sentence, eax
    mov ebx, OFFSET sentence
    mov ecx, [LENGTHOF sentence]
    checkint:
        mov eax, intIndex
        cmp eax, intEnd
        je done
        mov edx, count
        L1:
            call DumpRegs
            cmp al, [ebx]
            jne no_inc
            cmp al, 00
            je none
            incre:
                inc dl
            no_inc:
                add ebx, 8
        jmp L1
            none:
                mov intIndex, eax
                call WriteChar
                call DumpRegs
                mov count, edx
                mov edx, OFFSET dash
                call WriteString
                call DumpRegs
                mov eax, count
                call WriteInt
                mov eax,intIndex
                inc eax
                mov intIndex, eax
                call DumpRegs
                mov count, eax
                jmp checkint
        done:
            RET
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int startint = 48;
    int endint = 57;
    int startupper = 65;
    int endupper = 90;
    int startlower = 97;
    int endlower = 122;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter the string you would like to count: ";
    string sentence;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = startint; i < endint; i++)
    {
        for (char a : sentence)
        {
            if (a == i)
                count++;
        }
        if(count !=0)
        cout << (char)i << " - " << count<<endl;
        count = 0;
    }
    for (int i = startupper; i < endupper; i++)
    {
        for (char a : sentence)
        {
            if (a == i)
                count++;
        }
        if(count !=0)
        cout << (char)i << " - " << count<<endl;
        count = 0;
    }
    for (int i = startlower; i < endlower; i++)
    {
        for (char a : sentence)
        {
            if (a == i)
                count++;
        }
        if(count !=0)
        cout << (char)i << " - " << count<<endl;
        count = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tips: use a debugger.  Single-step through your code and watch register values change.  It will often be easy to spot when you made an obvious error, or at least to discover where something stops behaving the way you designed so you can investigate further.

Comment: Your formatting at the top hurts my brain.

Comment: I tried the debugger and changed some of my code and now it won't end the loop
I updated the code in my post

Comment: Comment your code to describe how it's supposed to work.  In the infinite loop, look at the register that the loop-branch checks.  If you want anyone to debug your code for you, include info about what values were in which registers at which instruction.

Comment: I wrote the c++ on what its supposed to do because I'm not that great at explaining and it helps me understand how to write the assembly better but all it does is in the sentence it'll count the number of each characters
so if the sentence is "Hello" the output would be
H - 1,
e - 1,
l - 2,
o - 1

I also noticed that my code was not reading the string correctly, instead it stores a symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> call ReadString
> mov sentence, eax
> mov ebx, OFFSET sentence
> mov ecx, [LENGTHOF sentence]
> ```

The *ReadString* function returns the size of the input in the `EAX` register. Yet you use this as an address!

```
call     ReadString
mov      sentence, eax         ;This is a length !
mov      ebx, OFFSET buffer
mov      ecx, sentence
```

---

> ```
> cmp al, [ebx]
> jne no_inc
> cmp al, 00
> je none
> ```

Check for the end of the string before doing anything else:

```
cmp     byte ptr [ebx], 0
je      none
cmp     al, [ebx]
jne     no_inc
```

---

Since *count* is a dword, increment `EDX` rather than `DL`.
Since strings use 1 byte per character, add just 1 to `EBX` in stead of 8.

---

> ```
> checkint:
> mov eax, intIndex
> cmp eax, intEnd
> je done
> ```

This way you'll miss the final iteration! Only jump to *done* when `EAX` is **above** *intEnd*:

```
checkint:
    mov     eax, intIndex
    cmp     eax, intEnd
    ja      done
```

I hope this helps to get the main code working...

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful! (: